# Carto OSM in TileMill- How to change to an other Stylesheet

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

I'm doing my first steps with CartoOSM in TileMill. 
But since it has about twenty stylesheets (.mss) I can't see them all in TileMill because (depending on Window-Size) just the first six stylesheets are shown.

So how can I see the others ? I haven't found a way, yet!

Thanks for your answers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a known bug](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/190) in Tilemill.

One easy workaround for this is to simply edit your mss files in your preferred text editor. Once you save your changes in your mss file, tilemill will re-render the map based on your changes to your mss file.